# Function from button change to press key. HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple game script in JS but only way to accelerate object is pushbutton

```
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.1)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.1)">speed ++</button>
```

there is function:

```
function accelerate(n) {
    test.gravity = n;
}
```

And question is How to change button click to key press for accelarate?
Basically I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add listener to window.document object for example

```
const test = {
    gravity: 0.0
};

window.document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  // arrow up
  if (e.keyCode === 38) accelerate(0.1);
  // arrow down
  if (e.keyCode === 40) accelerate(-0.1);

  console.log(test.gravity);
})

function accelerate (n) {
    test.gravity = n;
}
```